# How to find all equals paths in degenerate tree from specific start vertex?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, sum, doubly-linked-list

I have some `degenerate tree` (it looks like as array or doubly linked list). For example, it is this tree:

[image]

Each edge has some weight. I want to find all equal paths, which starts in each vertex.

Let edges have the following weights (it is just example):

`a-b = 3`

`b-c = 1`

`c-d = 1`

`d-e = 1`

Then:

1. The vertex `A` does not have any equal path (there is no vertex from left side).
2. The vertex `B` has one equal pair. The path `B-A` equals to the path `B-E` `(3 == 3)`.
3. The vertex `C` has one equal pair. The path `B-C` equals to the path `C-D` `(1 == 1)`.
4. The vertex `D` has one equal pair. The path `C-D` equals to the path `D-E` `(1 == 1)`.
5. The vertex `E` does not have any equal path (there is no vertex from right side).

I implement simple algorithm, which works in `O(n^2)`. But it is too slow for me.

Comment: Why in you example the vertex `C` does not have such paths? Is not `C-B` equal to `C-D`?

Comment: @Petr, it is my mistake. This path is correct.

Comment: @David Is the constraint that when you have a node, the path-cost from the node to the parent, must equal the path cost from the node `n` to some descendant `n'`?

Comment: @VivinPaliath, yep, you're right. We chose some vertex V, Then we iterate all ancestors and descendants vertices and try to find such two vertices V1 and V2 , that path from V1 to V equal to path from V to V2.

Comment: So, just for further clarification, if in the example above all the weights were 1, then C-A would equal C-E (2 == 2)? I.e. it doesn't necessarily have to be the parent, just some ancestor?

Comment: So you want all tuples (v1, v, v2) where v1 and v2 are an *arbitrary* ancestor and descendant such that c(v1, v) = c(v, v2)? In your examples I see that v1 is always a parent. What if the path cost from a-b was 1 instead of three? Then would you consider C-A and C-E part of the solution? It seems you would have to, going by your definition.

Comment: @mwm314, you're right. If in the example above all the weights were 1, then C-A would equal C-E (2 == 2)

Comment: @VivinPaliath, yes, I just want all tuples (v1, v, v2), where c(v1, v) = c(v, v2). If a-b is 1, then C-A and C-E is good solution.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Especially since you've already got an answer.

Comment: @amit, It seems, that answer is wrong, or I don't understand it.

Comment: @David Then comment, edit your question and add a bounty on it to get more attention. Don't ask the same question twice.